# OpenGL Multiple Render Targets - Can the default framebuffer be a target?

Tags: opengl

I would like to draw to multiple render targets, with one of those targets being the default framebuffer.  The reason for this is to achieve multisampling in the default framebuffer, while still writing to a texture more information about the scene.

If I just use normal multiple render targets (via an FBO with two color attachments) I can render both my scene and extra information, but both images do not support multisampling, and when I draw the scene to the screen as a full screen quad I lose multisampling.  So, I am curious if I can render the scene as normal to the default framebuffer, preserving multisampling support, while also rendering the scene to the FBO I have created.

The area I am looking right now is [GlDrawBuffers](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml), but I am not sure if I am on the right track.

I know there is support in OpenGL 3.2 for GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, but I do not have the luxury of running on OpenGL 3.2 hardware, so I am trying to keep multisampling support while still writing to multiple render targets.

Comment: Use `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` if you want to benefit from MSAA without using multisample textures or the default framebuffer. You can blit a multisampled ***renderbuffer*** into the default framebuffer (or any singlesampled draw buffer for that matter, which could be another texture if you wanted), and it will do MSAA resolve for you.

Comment: I was under the impression a multisampled renderbuffer required the attachment of a multisampled texture?  The OpenGL examples show:  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, tex );

Comment: No, renderbuffers and textures are two separate things. Long before multisample ***texture*** support was around, GL still had the capability to draw into a multisampled renderbuffer attachment. The primary difference between renderbuffers and textures is how you display their contents - renderbuffers have to be blitted (copied), but textures can be sampled in a shader. You can copy a multisampled renderbuffer into a singlesampled buffer (which could be the default framebuffer, or a texture) using `glBlitFramebuffer (...)`, this will perform MSAA resolve.

Comment: Can I ask what you are using multisampling for? I had assumed anti-aliasing, but there are other uses. If it is just MSAA, then blitting from a renderbuffer attachment will probably work fine for you.

Comment: It is just MSAA.  I'm following the example at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling but it is requiring a multisample texture to be created.

Comment: From what I have seen of that code listing, a MS texture actually is not necessary. A renderbuffer would work just fine; have a look [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object). You just have to create and attach a Multisampled Renderbuffer instead of a texture in this case.

Comment: That worked well enough, although my performance isn't quite what I was looking for, so I'll probably have to keep tweaking.  Thanks for the help!  You can place one of your comments as an answer for me to accept if you would like.